# Linux Play Raw Sound from Waveform

Tags: c++, c, linux, audio

I'm in the process of building my own GameBoy emulator, the idea behind which is to convert a GameBoy flash ROM entirely into C code that can be run natively on the host computer. It's in the very early stages of development, and one of my roadblocks is that the GameBoy stores sound as a series of commands that edit one of four continuous wave forms. Basically, these sounds are always playing a flat tone unless you turn them off or modulate them by editing some register values. What this means is that I can't just `execvp("SomeMusicPlayer /path/to/sound.ext", NULL);`, because the sound isn't stored in a portable format. Furthermore, the idea is to rebuild the game as a single executable, so I'd like to be able to play sounds without forking to an external program.

In short, my question is: "How do I play sounds as raw waveforms with envelope and sweep functions on Linux?"

Comment: You find and download one that does, _or_ you read-up more about that particular sound generation chip and how it works, before implementing code that will perform the same way, producing the same output as the chip would have, as a wav. In either case, you'll need a library to play the sound and perhaps another one to decode it. Your first aim of converting the GameBoy rom into C to run natively on the host simply wont happen. It's far, far easier to pretend to be a cpu than it is to convert from one cpu/os to another - why do you think all emulators work the way they do already?

Comment: I don't care what's easy, I'm not trying to recreate something that's already been done, I want to do something new. I don't want to store the music separately, and any libraries that play sounds have been written once, so they can be written again.

Comment: Sure, just dont bank on doing anything else productive with your life then. The GameBoy SuperAdvance 10,000 will be released before code implementing your gba->pc native code is... The most obvious thing to do would be to generate the same audio that the chips do. You can read up about their registers, the functions of these regs and the chip's response to said input. This has already been done several times - there's no way around that, you re-do it or get code that already exists. Just like eveyone did with the OPL chips of the SoundBlaster or the Yamaha stuff inside SegaMS and Nintendos. :)

Comment: I'm not trying to do anything with a gba, I'm just using a generic GameBoy from 1989, 8-bit Z-80 processor and all that. I can figure out what waveforms are being represented in the ROM pretty easily, what I want to know is how to output them once I do. Even using a library to do it is fine.

Comment: The best choice is `libsdl`, which is basically Linux's DirectX. If you have a raw waveform, you can easily output it by looking up [how to output audio](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_OpenAudioDevice). If you have multiple basis waveforms you want to mix together, you can [look that up](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_MixAudioFormat) as well. If you don't have the basis waveforms, you have to figure out how the sound chip works and emulate it to produce them.